# При сборки проекта, браузеры не видят svg-спрайты

Tags: html, xml, google-chrome, svg, gulp

При запущенном gulp'е, спрайты отлично видны.
Но когда собираю проект, Chrome пишет вот-такое
[image: SVG error]
Что делать уже и не знаю!

Comment: хром запрещает читать файлы по протоколу file://

Comment: указывай относительные пути, а не абсолютные